# Combining logic statements AND in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What would be the way to select elements when two conditions are `True` in a matrix?
In R, it is basically possible to combine vectors of booleans.

So what I'm aiming for:

```
A = np.array([2,2,2,2,2])
A < 3 and A > 1  # A < 3 & A > 1 does not work either
```

Evals to:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

It should eval to:

```
array([True,True,True,True,True])
```

My workaround usually is to sum these boolean vectors and equate to 2, but there must be a better way. What is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could just use `&`, eg:

```
x = np.arange(10)
(x<8) & (x>2)
```

gives

```
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

A few details:

- This works because `&` is shorthand for the numpy ufunc `bitwise_and`, which for the `bool` type is the same as `logical_and`.  That is, this could also be spelled out as
  `bitwise_and(less(x,8), greater(x,2))`
- You need the parentheses because in numpy `&` has higher precedence than `<` and `>`
- `and` does not work because it is ambiguous for numpy arrays, so rather than guess, numpy raise the exception.

Comment: The parentheses are also important.  `x<8 & x>2` will fail with a similar error.

Comment: Also, it does not work with `and` instead of `&`, interestingly. Why does this work?

Comment: I prefer this solution because it's more logical to me (pun intended), and it's shorter.

Comment: You can't override the `and` operator in Python.

Answer (score 8):

There's a function for that:

```
In [8]: np.logical_and(A < 3, A > 1)
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Since you can't override the `and` operator in Python it always tries to cast its arguments to `bool`. That's why the code you have gives an error.

Numpy has defined the `__and__` function for arrays which overrides the `&` operator. That's what the other answer is using.

Comment: This will only work for two comparisons. If you have more comparions. for some reason `logical_and` works in an unexpected way.

Answer (score -1):

While this is primitive, what is wrong with

```
A = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
b = []
for i in A:
  b.append(A[i]>1 and A[i]<3)
print b
```

The output is [True, True, True, True, True]

Comment: This scales terribly.

Comment: It defeats the whole purpose of using numpy for speed. There are trivial vectorized alternatives, as seen in the other answers.