# Create new 2d numpy array based on threshold values from other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 2d-arrays, which I want to use to initialize a new 2d array.
The new 2d-array should be populated with either a 0 or 1 in position (x,y) depending on the values in the (x,y) positions of the other 3 arrays.

For example, I have these 3 2d-arrays:

```
A = [[2, 3, 6],    B = [[5, 9, 0],    C = [[2, 7, 6],
     [9, 8, 3],         [2, 4, 3],         [2, 1, 6],
     [1, 0, 5]]         [4, 5, 1]]         [4, 6, 8]]
```

And a logic function:

```
D = (A > 4 && B < 5 && C > 5)
```

This should create the 2d-array:

```
D = [[0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1]]
```

Now I can do this with 2 for loops, but I was wondering if there is a faster numpy way?

**EDIT**:

Here is a sample of my real code:

```
val_max = 10000
a = np.asarray(array_a)
b = np.asarray(array_b)
d = ((a >= val_max) and (b >= val_max)).astype(int)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyze.py", line 70, in <module>
    d = ((a >= val_max) and (b >= val_max)).astype(int)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**EDIT2**:

I should have used `&` operator instead of `and` (similar for '|' vs. `or`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996661/combining-logic-statements-and-in-numpy-array might also solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given A, B, and C, you just have to convert them into numpy arrays and compute for D using:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray(A)
B = np.asarray(B)
C = np.asarray(C)

D = ((A > 4) & (B < 5) & (C > 5)).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this produces `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: hmm.. I rechecked everything using the sample that you gave and it worked. could you post a screenshot of your code?

Comment: you can also try `D = np.logical_and(A > 4, np.logical_and(B < 5, C > 5)).astype(int)`.

Comment: Yeah, I rechecked with the sample and that works, but it doesn't work with my arrays hmm.. I will update the main post with more info on my real data.

Comment: Aah, I found the mistake. I used `and` instead of `&` operator

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray(A)
B = np.asarray(B)
C = np.asarray(C)
D = ((A > 4) & (B < 5) & (C > 5)).astype(int)
```