# Python: numpy array larger and smaller than a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to look for numbers that is between a range?

```
c = array[2,3,4,5,6]
>>> c>3
>>> array([False, False, True, True, True]
```

However, when I give c in between two numbers, it return error

```
>>> 2<c<5
>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The desire output is

```
array([False, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining logic statements AND in numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996661/combining-logic-statements-and-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this,

```
(c > 2) & (c < 5)
```

**Result**

```
array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 4):

Python evaluates `2<c<5` as `(2<c) and (c<5)` which would be valid, except the `and` keyword doesn't work as we would want with numpy arrays. (It attempts to cast each array to a single boolean, and that behavior can't be overridden, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i).) So for a vectorized `and` operation with numpy arrays you need to do this:

`(2<c) & (c<5)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
output = [(i and j) for i, j in zip(c>2, c<5)]
```

Output :

```
[False, True, True, False, False]
```